# How to calculate how much each error source contributes to an overall accuracy metric?

Tags: modeling, convolution

I am building a model of overall accuracy for a robotic system, I have various error sources from assembly, calibrations, measurements, imaging, for each error I have a PDF of the error it induces on the tip of the robot, I have combined all error sources via convolution.
I want to assess how much each error source contributes to the overall accuracy.
I tried calculating the significance of each source via the variance, is there a better/more correct/accurate way of getting how much each error source contributes?

$$ \textrm{Significance}(\%) = \frac{u^2_{(x_i)}}{\sum_{i=1}^nu^2_{(x_i)}}$$